# How to change class in a list of items just to element that i clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add to take a class of an element to click, to the first click to put my class and to the second to take out my class. I only managed to add the class to the first click and I can't get it back to normal on the second click on the item. I also tried toggle but something is missing and I don't know what. Thanks :D

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    items.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
  })
});
```

```css
.list {
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 700px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.active {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the active state of the clicked element before removing the `active` class from all the elements. Then, you can set the active state of the clicked element to the opposite of what it was.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Get the active state of the clicked element
    let active = this.classList.contains("active");
    items.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    // Toggle the active state of the clicked element
    if(active){
      this.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      this.classList.add("active");    
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.list {
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 700px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.active {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!It's works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop through all elements every time. You can just look up the currently active element. This should work:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Check if clicked element is active
    if (this.classList.contains("active")){
      // Element was active, deactivate and terminate
      this.classList.remove("active");
      return;
    }
    // Element clicked was not active
    // Find active element in list and deactivate, if any
    var activeElement = document.querySelector(".list .active");
    if (activeElement != null) activeElement.classList.remove("active");
    this.classList.add("active");
  })
});
```

See [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6x8ndko1/).

Comment: While this works, the added if/then logic, coupled with the need to scan for the active element upon each click and also the extra branching of the `return` makes this solution less than ideal. Just looping over all the elements and removing the `active` class is simpler and in many cases (like this one) more efficient.

Comment: How is it more efficient to loop through all elments no matter what? The solution above terminates the function if the clicked element is active, after deactivating it. It's also rather intuitive, as that's how a human would manually do this. Less written code doesn't mean more efficient.

Comment: This isn't about more or less code, it's about the efficiency and comprehensibility of the code. Once the desired elements have been added to a node list, which is an array-like object, looping over that list is a trivial operation (array traversal is fast). Your solution requires re-scanning the DOM upon each click to find the active element and possibly branching out of the function. Again, while the solution works, it's less efficient than the fairly standard approach to this kind of use case and includes more code paths, which makes it a little harder to comprehend and debug.